# Easiest way to set attribute's value in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, attributes

Which is the easiest way to load a different picture every time I select a specific choice by a list of the available choices of a spinner in Kotlin?

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mypic" />
```

Is it possible to directly set  `srcCompat` attribute's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly set srcCompat attribute's value like this: `imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_plus)`

Comment: Thanks! It works fine with Android's default image set, but how can I select my own picture?

I try `imageView.setImageResource(res.drawable.my_pic)`, but it seems my_pic is not accessible.

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_pic)`